# how to handle empty JSON responses?

Tags: javascript, json

```
[]
```

this is the JSON response i'm getting when calling a webservice. i need to print **nothing to show** if the response is empty.

```
$http({ 
        method:'POST', 
        url: 'http://xxxxxx',
        headers: { 
           Content-Type: 'application/json', 
           Accept: 'application/json'
        }, 
        data: JSON.stringify(x)
}).then(function (response) { 
        $scope.details=response.data;
        if($scope.invoiceDetails == null){
           console.log("nothing to show");
        }
    });
```

This is the code i'm using now. But it is not working. Someone please give me some suggestions.

Comment: what is `typeof response.data`

Comment: `response.data.length==0`??

Comment: alert(typeof response.data); is **object **

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
if (response.data.length === 0)
{
    console.log("nothing to show");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($scope.details.length === 0)
{
    console.log("nothing to show");
}
```

Comment: Duplicate and without description

Comment: This won't work in all situations. If details will be undefined, you will get a Type error Cannot read property 'length' of null...

Answer (score -1):

You are checking some other variable in your if condition.

```
  $http({ method:'POST', 
                url: 'http://xxxxxx',
                headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                'Accept': 'application/json'
                }, 
                data: JSON.stringify(x)
                 }).then(function (response) { 

     $scope.details=response.data;

    if(!$scope.details){
    console.log("nothing to show");
    }

    OR
    //if your details is an array
    if(!$scope.details || $scope.details.length <= 0){
    console.log("nothing to show");
    }

    //You can also check for empty objects like this
    if(angular.equals({}, $scope.items)){
    console.log("nothing to show");
    }
```

Comment: Can I know why I have been down voted? Leave a reason if you down vote.

Comment: Try your own answer.

Comment: @Durga updated answer? and what should I check it for?

Comment: @Durga so I am doing this too, check my answer. //if your details is an array
    if(!$scope.details || $scope.details.length <= 0){
    console.log("nothing to show");
    } I have this in my answer.

Comment: `!$scope.details` will be always false, then why to check??

Comment: How can you be sure? What if it comes as undefined or null? When you code you code for unforeseen validation errors too. And I have given all the different scenarios as well.

Comment: @Durga don't just downvote without further asking and understanding what is actually happening.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (response!=undefined)
{
    //your code here
}
else{
console.log("nothing to show");
}
```

something like this

Comment: if the response is `[]` it won't be undefined.